# Shell Script is not reading optional parameter correctly

Tags: shell, sh

I have this script file:

```
#!/bin/sh

Show_Error() {
        echo -e "\033[31m ERROR \033[0m $1"
}

if [ "$1" = "-help" ]
then
    echo "<input> - input file name or input URL"
else


for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -l=*|--ddloc=*)
    DDLOC="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -l|--ddloc)
    shift # past argument
    DDLOC="$1"
    shift # past value
    ;;
    *)
          # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done

if [ -z "$DDLOC" ]
then
       Show_Error 'File is missing. Use -l or --ddloc.'
else
echo "Location::: $DDLOC"
fi
fi
```

If i run command:
`./tdl2ddlgen.sh -s sssss -m lll -l LOC`

It is giving `"Location::: sssss"` intead of `"Location::: LOC"`

Comment: `shift` does nothing useful in the `for` loop. You already have a list of arguments, `"$@"`, and `$i` is traversing this list one by one. The `shift` won't do anything to the list of arguments which has already been expanded in the `for` statement.

Comment: `Show_Error` sounds like a function which prints an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr: `echo "..." >&2`

Answer (score 1):

You can consider that `for i in "$@"` copies all the values from `$@` and then sets `$i` to each in turn. You can watch what is happening by instrumenting your code:

```
for i in "$@"
do
echo "\$i = $i; \$@ = ($@)"
case $i in
    # ...
```

giving output:

```
$i = -s; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = sssss; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = -m; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = 111; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = -l; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = LOC; $@ = (-m 111 -l LOC)
Location::: sssss
```

What is actually going wrong is that you don't shift away `$1` when you get an unknown 
option. If you add the shift:

```
for i in "$@"
do
echo "\$i = $i; \$@ = ($@)"
case $i in
    -l=*|--ddloc=*)
    DDLOC="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -l|--ddloc)
    shift # past argument
    DDLOC="$1"
    shift # past value
    ;;
    *)
          # unknown option
    shift
    ;;
esac
done
```

then you will get the result you were expecting:

```
$i = -s; $@ = (-s sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = sssss; $@ = (sssss -m 111 -l LOC)
$i = -m; $@ = (-m 111 -l LOC)
$i = 111; $@ = (111 -l LOC)
$i = -l; $@ = (-l LOC)
$i = LOC; $@ = ()
Location::: LOC
```

although the behaviour is still not quite correct - `LOC` argument is processed twice. To prevent the double-processing, rather than copying `$@` for your loop, you could do:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
case $1 in
    # ...
```